# How to display image taken with camera in Android

Tags: android, image, camera

I'm trying to write an app that will take a picture with the native Android Camera app and then display the picture I just took in a new activity. This is my take picture method.

```
private static File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
            );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        int t =5;
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

This works; the camera app opens up and the image is saved. However, this is my display image method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String j = MainActivity.mCurrentPhotoPath;
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(j);

    ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    setContentView(myImage);
}
```

Now I tested to see if the filename path was being recorded, and it was. String j does indeed have the path. But, the system cannot run the .decodeFile(String j) method; it says that no such file exists. What do I do to display the image?

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` expects a file path, as returnad by `File.getAbsolutePath()`; the **file:** prefix probably causes the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the native camera, you will get the resulting picture in `onActivityResult()` given that you start the camera app using `startActivityForResult()`. You can then get a reference to the picture's path as follows (from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)):

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}
```

You can then pass this path to the new `Activity` via an `Intent` and decode the `Bitmap` accordingly.

Comment: The "Toast" doesn't display on the screen, but the image was captured; it can be accessed through the myFiles android app